# How would I find the first Integer to satisfy equation?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-distribution, maple

During a test at school today the following question was asked - (Translated from Danish, please ask if the question is unclear)

> At a workplace, consisting of 50 members, there is a 7% chance that a given worker is using the toilet at any time.
>
> Assume every worker has the same chance of being at the toilet at any time, and that their toilet visits are all independent of one another
>
> What is the minimum number of toilets required, such that the probability of a queue forming outside the toilet is less that 5%?

Is there an 'elegant' way to solve this question?

## How we all solved it

Talking to class-mates after the test - turns out we all did the same thing to solve this question. We were allowed to use maple so we defined a cumulative distribution function:

$$cdf(n,p,t):=\sum_{i=0}^t \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$

And simply guessed the number:

$$cdf(50,0.07,6)=0.0583136357$$
$$cdf(50,0.07,7)=0.0220099488$$

So the answer became "It would take 7 toilets"

This is just an unsatisfying way to solve the problem, and dosent look that great either.

### Additional attempts

When I got home, I tried to use maples "solve()" function to do something like:

$$solve(cdf(50,0.07,t)=0.05)$$

But maple could not find an answer there, so then I got desperate and tried things like:

$$solve(min(cdf(50,0.07,t)<0.05))$$

Which clearly was not going anywhere either, and now im out of ides.

So my question: Would you solve this question in a different manner? - if so how?

Comment: You can say the mean number of workers wanting the toilet is $3.5$ and the standard deviation is $\approx1.804$ so the mean plus two standard deviations is about $7.1.$  Still, that's just a first approximation.  I don't see how to answer the question without doing the calculation you did.

Comment: My answer was deleted, even though it does indeed show what you asked: how to do it elegantly in Maple. `cdf:=sum(binomial(n,i)*p^i*(1-p)^(n-i),i=0..t): ceil(fsolve(1-eval(cdf,[n=50,p=0.07])=0.05,t=1..10.0));` And you could even use the range `0..infinity` and avoid the burden of finding an upper value. More efficient (but more coding) would be a binary search for the integer solution, rather than a `ceil` of a float result whose extra accuracy is irrelevant. But you'd still need the upper estimate. Forming a piecewise-linear function from the integer values would be even more efficient.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of answer you want. What would be "elegant"? Are you looking for a short and simple way to solve it in Maple, possibly without simply using its `Statistics` package? Is a floating-point  (numeric) methodology OK? Do you need proof justification of any such approach, and if so then need it be understandable by a high-school student? If this was intended as a programming question then it'd be more suitable on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Where you show results like `cdf(50,0.07,6)=0.0583136357` did you perhaps intend to write `1-cdf(50,0.07,6)=0.0583136357`?

Comment: @acer Yes, I did indeed mean 1 -..

Comment: @acer I can't really clarify what kind of answer I want, as I have no idea what options are available. That being said, this was not intended as a programming question. What I was looking for was some way to find the solution - without having to plot in values for t myself, and your "t..infinity" solution does indeed solve that issue, and provides some additional info. I will not accept it just yet though - just because someone else might have a different take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of an extension of the factorial function for non-integer values. Ie, n! = Γ(n + 1)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial_of_non-integer_values

This allows us to obtain a continuous representation for which stock numeric rootfinding can be used. This allows for a short and simple approach using Maple.

Moreover, this approach removes the need to first discover an integer value of `t` for which the probability is less than 5%.

First I'll show it alongside some explanation, and then I'll show the short code the obtains the result.

NB. Your Question is tagged with `Maple`, and you show Maple code attempts to solve the problem, hence it very much appears that this is one kind of answer for which you are looking.

```
restart;
expr := binomial(n,i)*p^i*(1-p)^(n-i):

ext := convert(expr, GAMMA);

    GAMMA(1+n)/GAMMA(1+i)/GAMMA(n-i+1)*p^i*(1-p)^(n-i)
```

Here is `sum(ext, i=0..t)`, simplified only for convenience.

```
new := simplify(subs(P=1-p,simplify(algsubs(1- 
                     p=P,expand(sum(ext, i=0..t))))),
                power)
          assuming t::posint, i::posint, i<=t,
                   n::posint, t<n, P>0, P<1;

     1-GAMMA(1+n)/GAMMA(2+t)/GAMMA(n-t)*p^(t+1)
       *(1-p)^(-1+n-t)*hypergeom([1,1-n+t,[2+t],p/(-1+p))
```

We can check agreement at some positive integer values of `t`.

```
1 - evalf(eval(eval(Sum(expr, i=0..t),[n=50,p=0.07]), t=6));

              0.0583136357

1 - evalf(eval(eval(new,[n=50,p=0.07]), t=6));

              0.0583136357

1 - evalf(eval(eval(Sum(expr, i=0..t),[n=50,p=0.07]), t=7));

              0.0220099488

1 - evalf(eval(eval(new,[n=50,p=0.07]), t=7));

              0.0220099488
```

We can superimpose plots involving the discrete function and this continuous extension.

```
plots:-display(
  plot([seq([t,1-eval(Sum(expr, i=0..t),[n=50,p=0.07])], t=5..10)],
       style=point, color=blue, symbol=solidcircle, symbolsize=15),
  plot(1-eval(new,[n=50,p=0.07]), t=5..10),
  plot(0.05, t=5..10, color=gray)
);
```

[image]

Using numeric root-finding it is now simple to find the value of `t` for which this attains a value of 0.05 .

Note that we do not have the burden of supplying a value of `t` for which the probability was less than 0.05 .

```
rt := fsolve(1-eval(new,[n=50,p=0.07])=0.05,
             t=1..infinity);

           rt := 6.167238357
```

The next integer higher than that root

```
ceil(rt);
                7
```

And, without all the exposition,

```
restart;
cdf:=sum(binomial(n,i)*p^i*(1-p)^(n-i),i=0..t): 
ceil(fsolve(1-eval(cdf,[n=50,p=0.07])=0.05,t=1..infinity));

                 7
```